# Is there any way to update the Bootcamp assistant app?

Tags: macbook-pro, bootcamp

We have a late 2011 MBP here and ideally I could do with having the more recent bootcamp assistant due to the various options available.

I can't seem to be able to edit the plist as shown in previous similar questions.

even with a sudo chmod 777 etc (yes I know 777 is overkill)

I would appreciate any help with this as really can't be doing with sourcing a legitimate CD and license for W7/8 in 2017

Thanks for help in advance

Comment: I always thought BCA version was tied to the OS - what OS does the machine have?

Comment: High Sierra, however this has an optical drive and as such you have to edit the info.plist to tell it to use USB (which I can't manage atm)

Answer (score 1):

Basically Macs what originally were shipped with optical drives should use their drive to install Windows. If your optical drive is not longer available, virtual machine software such as VirtualBox can be substituted, but the installation process becomes significantly more complex. **Usually a USB drive can not be used to install any version of Windows on such Macs**.

The good news is your machine probably can run Windows 7, 8, 8.1 and 10. If Apple does not support a new versioner of Windows, generally the older drivers can be used to install Windows. I have the current version of Windows 10 running on 2007 and 2011 iMacs.

Also, you probably will need to install Windows to boot using the legacy BIOS boot method. The primary reason for this has to due with the Windows Support Software provided by Apple. The drivers included are designed for a BIOS boot and therefore can cause problems if one attempts as installation using a EFI boot method.

Comment: I understand however you can edit the info.plist to enable the USB drive option, however I'm having issues editing the plist so looking for another way.

Comment: I assumed you were trying to create a Windows USB installer so you could install Windows on your 2011 MBP. In any case, you can create the USB installer without using the Boot Camp Assistant, which is a lot easier than trying to edit  the plist.